# Move all email from one folder in Outlook to another

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I can't figure out how to move all emails from a folder that I created a long time ago back to the inbox. I have there over a thousand emails. I tried to select all emails, but drag and drop didn't work, and it didn't give me the option to move either online or desktop.

I created a rule to move all emails to the inbox, but it didn't run and didn't give me the option to run now.

Comment: When you select the emails in a folder, use the Move icon in the Ribbon and select Inbox as the target of the Move.  Does that work for you?

Comment: If you can't move all at once, select the first hundred messages and drag-drop them to the correct folder. Then the next hundred... BTW, it might appear nothing is happening, because the process on the mail server could be slow, so be patient after each move.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the below options?

1.Select the emails > right click > **Move**:

[image]

2.Create a rule > **Run this rule now on messages already in "Inbox"**.Please note rule is used for emails in Inbox but not other folders.

[image]

Comment: Is there any update?